# Options to access Kafka stream transformation history?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building an application which should retrieve stream transformations history for particular consumer, assuming that I haven't access to the consumer's source code.

Are there any way to access transformations history through Kafka API? If not then, are there any possible alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by `topic transformations history`?

Comment: I meant stream related to particular topic

Comment: More precisely: can I get transformations within each consumer subscribed to Kafka cluster without direct access to source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it in that way, but you could build your transformations such that they stored metadata about transformation done to the messages, either as part of the message value, or its [Header](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/header/package-summary.html), added through [KIP-82](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers)/[KAFKA-4208](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4208) in Apache Kafka 0.11